# Apache doesn't recognize a local zone (BIND) unless restarted frequently

Tags: macports, apache

Apache does not recognize the local zone `.dev` -- returns 404 Not Found. If Apache is restarted it will recognize the local zon. If inactive for ~1hr it no longer recognizes the local zone -- returns to 404 Not Found.

**Configurations**

```
# /etc/named.conf
...
zone "dev" IN {
    type master;
    file "dev.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
...
```

Used [wildcard subdomains](http://clintberry.com/2011/wildcard-sub-domains-on-osx-web-development-on-localhost/) to enable this feature.

Comment: I don't see how this can be something directly related to Apache. How are your hostnames resolving when you can't reach the webserver?

Comment: @Gerry I will get back to you on that, have to wait till it stops working. What gets me though is that when Apache is restarted it works again. To me it seems like a module or service within Apache which shuts down and the restart refreshes it.

Comment: Also check Apache's error log.

Comment: @Gerry You were right it isn't Apache, when pinged: `ping: cannot resolve http://go.dev/: Unknown host`, but how would restarting Apache fix the issue?

Comment: It is `named` which is having issues, when restarted Apache picked up the domain without needing to be restarted.

Comment: You should exclude the 'http://' when pinging. `ping go.dev`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4085/discussion-between-gerry-and-ryan-schumacher)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue probably is in named.conf.  Check for errors with named-checkconf and look at your logs in var/log/* (depends on distro).  Additionally, look at /etc/syslog.conf for logging options.

Comment: `named-checkconf` returns no errors and `/var/log/*` doesn't have anything distinguishable. My distro is Lion and `/etc/syslog.conf` doesn't contain any reference to `named` should I add a directive to log `named` there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following terminal command to restart Apache.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

NOTE: You'll need to enter the admin password.

Comment: Sorry my question may have been a little confusing. I am not asking how to restart Apache (I already do this, frequently) rather I am asking how do I fix the issue: "Apache looses ability to pick up local zone; requires restart"

Comment: Ah. I'm afraid you're way out of my league now. :) I've only just mastered setting up vhosts.